# Telerik mvc3 treeview get node level client-side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, treeview, telerik, client-side

I have a treeview with check box.
When a check box is clicked, I need, client-side, to know the node level of the node just selected. exemple:

```
[ ] Node (level 1)
  [x] Node (level 2)
  [ ] Node (level 2)
  [ ] Node (level 2)
  [ ] Node (level 2)
[ ] Node (level 1)
  [ ] Node (level 2)
  [ ] Node (level 2)
  [ ] Node (level 2)
```

I dont see any property in the event parameter that could tell the level of the node.
A viable workaround would be to add, server side, an attribute to the node to indicate the level (for exemple `data-level="1"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should return the level of a node:

```
var level = $(e.item).parents(".t-item").length;
```

What it does is to find all parent elements that have the "t-item" CSS class which happen to be the parent nodes.

Comment: Well that seems like it would works. I would have prefered to add a tag to the item for the level. My colleague is sick today so I will not try it until tomorrow.